# Windows 7 Aero theme

Tags: wpf, windows-7, themes

I've already check [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf/) and the web for my problem, but I can't find any answer.

I can't find a way to have the Windows 7 Aero theme working. I mean, I have the Aero style from PresentationFramework.Aero, but it has the Vista look, the blue selection is not exactly the same.

This is the Windows 7 theme in Windows Explorer

[image]

And this is mine (the Aero look, I got by follow this thread)

[image]

I Have already managed to do the same ,as windows 7, by hand, but it's a pain to have to style every control, in order to retrieve this effect. Do you know if there is any way to get the Windows 7 Aero?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve this out-of-the-box. The default WPF List- and TreeView controls are extremely lacking in functionality (compared to the native counterparts) and the whole WPF Aero theme is severely missing polish. It wasn't updated for Windows 7 (which Aero-variant looks also better than Vista), and it doesn't even look like Vista. Apparently many people are satisfied with a half-assed copycat theme (also judging by lots of fake-looking Windows styles in UI toolkits).