# How can I load a WPF theme?

Tags: wpf

My understanding of the difference between a WPF theme and a WPF skin is the following:

- A WPF skin is a set of resources loaded by an application.
- A WPF theme is a set of resources handled by the OS.

To load a skin, I can just call Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add (mySkin);

However, I don't see any way to load a theme.

Is this documented or available?

Should I access the System.Windows.SystemResources internal class?

Answer (score 4):

You can load them as a ResourceDictionary:

```
<Window
  x:Class=”TestProject.Window1?
  xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation”
  xmlns:x=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml”>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary
    Source=”/presentationframework.aero;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml” />
  </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Note: You would need to have a reference to the PresentationFramework.Aero.dll.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a subtle difference between Skins and Themes, and the reason why you're having problems with what you're trying to do might stem from this:

> In WPF, a theming and skinning takes
>   on slight variations to their
>   meanings.  Theming refers to
>   controlling the look and consistency
>   of an application UI to match the
>   operating system.  For example, a WPF
>   application can be themed for the
>   Windows Aero theme or the Windows
>   Classic Theme.  Skinning refers to
>   changing the application's appearance.
>   In other words, applying or letting
>   the user pick a skin to change the
>   look and feel of the application.
>
> Robby Ingrebertsen, while working on
>   the WPF team, simplifies it as
>   follows:
>
> **Around here, we generally say that "theming" refers to the system theme
>    and "skinning" refers to changes to a specific app. This has helped to
>    clarify our internal communication**

From [here](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=14)

So essentially, if you want your app to look like one of the *Windows themes*,ie the current windows theme - you don't have to set any styles in your app and it'll chose a pre-defined XAML skin that resembles it automatically. But, if you want to style your application, you make a *skin* for the app as you're doing.

As far as loading the Windows themes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf) might help

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question)
The way to load a resource dictionary as a theme is to add it to the list of merged dictionaries of the generic.xaml resource dictionary.

Comment: Umm how is that any different from the answer I gave you 2 hours ago? Never mind I guess I didn't tell you to do it in the generic.xaml file but it will work wherever you do it.