# How to force to have Windows 7 theme on Windows Server 2003 for a WPF application

Tags: wpf

`enter code here`Is there any way to make a WPF app look like it's running on Windows 7 even if it's running on Windows Server 2003?

The propblem I am facing that due to default style on windows server 2003 on controls, its very hard to see the text content on them. For ex - Combo box

The text foreground is visible in black and highlighed animation color is dark blue which makes the text content hardly visible.

I have tried defining the following settings but it did not work

1. Edit the App.Xaml and change it to
2. Set the Copy Local property of referenced assembly PresentationFramework.Aero to True.

Please advice.

Comment: Not the question and only a comment.  This applies to 2008 Server - not 2003 Server.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947036

Answer (score 1):

WPF ships by default with these theme sets: Classic, Aero Normal, Luna Homestead, Luna Metatallic, Luna Normal, Roayle Normal....which allows WPF controls to match the look of a particular theme.

You can force WPF to use a specific theme by getting the Resources which a theme has defined in its theme assembly to be loaded into your App.Resources so your controls will use those themed styles.

See these links for more info:

- [Windows 7 theme for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf)
- http://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/

If you ever need access to the raw WPF theme designs, then you can download them from:

- http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812