# Using a Win8 theme on non-Win8 OSes

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I was wondering if it was possible (and how) to set a theme for all standard controls to match that of Windows 8. Not the Metro WinRT theme, but the Desktop version of Windows 8. It's more flat than Aero and looks more modern.

Is it possible to "bake in" this theme into my app?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325397/643085) might help you.

Comment: @HighCore, Thanks - that helped with forcing a theme (I was able to force a Luna theme on Win8). Where can I find the Win8 theme assembly? I don't even know how it's called (it's not Aero, right?)

Comment: @HighCore, Never mind - I found this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3dd4221-af4d-4ae4-a983-895db12ebcd0/what-is-the-theme-name-for-a-wpf-application-on-windows-8) which said that the theme is in PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll.

Comment: @HighCore, if you want to write the answer below, I'll mark it as "answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above:

You need to add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll` in your application and get the styles from there.

Comment: I just noticed that I ran into a problem - ClickOnce deploy for some reason does not include .Aero2.dll in the deploy. Any idea why?