# WPF RibbonWindow Metro Style

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5, ribbon

How can I make RibbonWindow look in metro style for Windows7? 
I have tried this solution https://github.com/D-Key/whosh but it brokes QuickAccess bar.

Comment: there is no big difference between normal Ribbonstyle and Metrostyle just take a look at office and how they did that in excel and word (like you will see they did nearly nothing it's all basic style inheritance)

Comment: How can I change RibbonWindow to metrostyle only by changing style?

Comment: it should change it style automatically based on the default style of your OS so if you are working on an Win8 OS your ribbon should looks like a Ribbon for Win8 BUT if you are talking about the App style your project need to be an App

Comment: I'm talking about win7. Updated question text.

Answer (score 1):

OK you will need to set an explicit theme for your project.

[How to set an explicit theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077528/1993545)

1. Add your Style dll to your application's references list as a requires
2. Edit your App.xaml

.

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <!--example style-->
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[What theme's are available in Win8?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3dd4221-af4d-4ae4-a983-895db12ebcd0/what-is-the-theme-name-for-a-wpf-application-on-windows-8?forum=wpf)

a quick search and i found *PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll* but there are sure some other styles