# Styling of WPF Controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Win forms application. I want to apply styling to all my controls in WPF.
For example my current button looks like 
[image]

```
<Button  Content="Add" Width="147" Height="31" Margin="490,10,10,10" />
```

I want to style the button, similar to the following (with curved borders)[image]

How can I do similar style to all the controls.

Comment: See [Style Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_basics) on MSDN.

Comment: The example that they show in the link have the window borders curved, like the button style i wanted. But by default none of my controls are like that. Should I add some theme to have that styling.

Comment: What operating system and version of .NET are you running?

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 and .net 4.5

Comment: Try the answer to the [Windows 7 theme for WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf) question.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify your requirement. My qualified guess is that you are looking for styling solution for WPF Button with rounded corners, like shown in my calculator app here: http://webinfocentral.com/VOLTA/Manual.aspx
If so then there are at least 2 solutions as following:

Create the ResourceDictionary file and reference it in your WPF XAML

Add the Button Style as shown in the following code snippet, which makes rounded corners (notice the Property `<Border.CornerRadius>2</Border.CornerRadius`>) and 3 visual/gradient effects specific to normal appearance, mouse over and pressed Button states:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Button_Default">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#202020"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="#606060">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Border.BorderThickness>0</Border.BorderThickness>
                    <Border.CornerRadius>2</Border.CornerRadius>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#f5f5f5" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#c5c5c5" Offset="0.93" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#606060" Offset="0.93" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#404040" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonBackground" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f5f5f5" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c5c5c5" Offset="0.81" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#606060" Offset="0.81" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#404040" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                               <Setter TargetName="ButtonBackground" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#e5e5e5" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#dfdfdf" Offset="0.75" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#606060" Offset="0.75" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#303030" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Note: pertinent to your case, you can add properties:*

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="147"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="31"/>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="490,10,10,10"/>
```

Add Button reference to the Style in XAML like following:

Alternatively, you can add Style to the Button In C# by adding reference to ResourceDictionary as follows (in this example you have to assign/use a button name):

```
[ButtonName].Style = this.Resources["Button_Default"] as Style;
```

Hope this will help. 
Rgds, Alex

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code. It may be helpful you.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
x:Name="Window"
Title="Window1"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Height="30" Width="150" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="2">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0.347"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7D91C0" Offset="0.656"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <ContentPresenter TextElement.FontSize="15" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="OK" Margin="172,43,269,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonControlTemplate1}"/>
</Grid>
```