# WindowChrome is not supported in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm brand new to WPF after using WinForms for years.  I'm trying to get a window that looks like a typical windows form with the blue border and red close button, or really anything that has a border like it shows in the middle 2 windows of the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstyle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). This is for .Net framework up to 4.8.1 but I am using .net 6.

[image: border1]

but my app always shows with no border:
[image: NoBorder]

Here is my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sim.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sim"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Simulator" Height="650" Width="1000"
        Icon="Resources/Sim.ico"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Power" Content="Power" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="OnPowerClick"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried to add WindowChrome after `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">`

```
    <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        
    </Setter>
```

but I get the error `"WindowChrome is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project."`

Is there a way to get an older style border in .net 6 wpf?

Comment: documentation states that pictures show the window styles on Windows Vista. do you have Windows Vista?

Comment: If I create a WinForms app on VS 2022, I get something close to your _chrome-less_ window on Win10.  The only difference is that the client rect is a light WinForms-y grey.  Windows appearance has always been determined (or at least greatly influenced by) the OS

Comment: I am developing a .net6.0 wpf on Windows 10.  Is there no way to get the older style border from .net framework 4.1 and/or Windows Vista?

Comment: Did you search and try anything? Dunno if this works but I readily found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf

Comment: Thanks @Andy I did search and documented what I tried. I did try the solution you linked to and it does not work.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for that.  Based on your answer I just set the background of the main panel and that looks much better.